# How to wrap synchronous function in promise using Q

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, q

I'm writing integration tests on a couple of functions using mocha, where some are sync and others async (returns Q promise).

I have three functions, `A`, `B` and `C`. Each function returns a value to be used by the next function.
`A` and `C` are sync, but `B` returns a promise. I need to call them in the order `A` > `B` > `C`.
If they were all sync, it would look like this: `C(B(A(args)))`.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
it('should pass this test', function () {
  return B(A('args'))
  .then(result => Q(C(result)))
  .then(result => {
      // bunch of assert statements
  })
})
```

I'm not a fan of this line: `.then(result => Q(C(result)))`

In `bluebird` I would just do `.then(Promise.method(C))`, but I have to use Q in this situation and I couldn't find a similar method in Q.

Is there a way to do this in Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `C`

```
return B(A('args'))
  .then(C)
  .then(resultOfC => ...
```

Comment: Ah, I see! then() can take both sync and async functions, I can't believe I didn't realize this before.